# Bash Linux Curl send headers from variable

Tags: linux, bash, curl, header

I have some script in bash.
I want to send a request to server with some headers (cloudflare block :).

I wrote this:

```
headers="\
-H 'Host: somesite.com' \
-H 'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
-H 'DNT: 1' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive'";

curl $headers somesite.com
```

But in output I'm have this..

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Accept-Language'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Accept'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'text'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'User-Agent'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'Mozilla'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '(Windows'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'NT'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '6.1;'
```

How can I put headers from variable into command ?

Comment: Try quoting the variable `curl "$headers" somesite.com`

Comment: To add to @TomFenech, best practice is to quote a variable when it contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a string for this. Trying to get quoting correct in a string like this is essentially impossible, use an array.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more.